# For Azure, can it support same IP address for different Availability Zone?

Tags: azure, zone, availability

For Azure, can I set same IP address subnet and addressing within different availability zone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. The availability zones are physical locations within a single Azure region. They are unique in terms of networking, power and cooling. Each availability zone can be made of 1 or more data centers. So the ip address you can get deploying to one zone or another will be different.